# Change coordinate of MKOverlay for an MKOverlayView

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, mkoverlay

I have an overlay on the map, and I would like to change its coordinates. To do this seamlessly I'm going to call the [setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayView) method after the change has been made to the view.

I've tested this out by just changing the fillColor and it works fine:

```
overlayView.fillColor = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3];
[overlayView setNeedsDisplayInMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect];
```

However I've seemingly hit a brick wall trying to also change the center coordinates of my overlay view (which is an [MKCircleView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircleView_class/Reference/Reference.html) with an [MKCircle](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKCircle_class/Reference/Reference.html)). There is a method in 
[MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation), which MKCircle conforms to, called [setCoordinate:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation) - which seems like what I need. Unfortunately though, the `circle` property in MKCircleView is readonly. Moreover the `overlay` property in [MKOverlayView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayView) is also readonly.

Is there actually a way of changing the coordinates for an overlay, without resort to remove the overlay view and adding a new one (which would cause very noticeable flicker on the screen.) ?

Comment: I've had similiar problem view MKPolyline. In my case the line always gets longer, so I always draw two polylines then remove the older one. This way the longer line hides the flicker.

Comment: i am also trying to acheive the same. in my case i have custom MKOverLay and want to animate it across the map.

Answer (score 0):

same problem is occurred here , so i'm creating set of method and calling it according to requirement.

```
-(void)removeAllAnnotationFromMapView{
    if ([[self.tmpMapView annotations] count]) {
        [self.tmpMapView removeAnnotations:[self.tmpMapView annotations]];
    }
}
-(void)removeAllOverlays{
    if ([[self.tmpMapView overlays] count]) {
        [self.tmpMapView removeOverlays:[self.tmpMapView overlays]];
    }
}

-(void)removeOverlayWithTag:(int)tagValue{
    for (MKOverlayView *oView in [self.tmpMapView overlays]) {
        if (oView.tag == tagValue) {
            [self.tmpMapView removeOverlay:oView];
        }
    }
}
```